# How do I fetch referenced objects when refreshing a Parse object?

Tags: parse-platform

I’ve got code like this:

```
[_session refreshInBackgroundWithBlock:/* something */];
```

The session (an instance of `PFObject`) references a `PFUser` object. Parse loads this dependency lazily, and it looks that refreshing the session drops the loaded user and I have to manually `-fetchIfNeeded` it later.

Is there a way to fully load the user when refreshing the session? Or, even better, is it possible to say that the `user` field should always be loaded when working with the session?

Comment: How did you get the session in the first place?

Comment: By calling `-getObjectInBackgroundWithId:block:` on a `PFQuery`. There I can tell Parse to fetch the referenced objects using `-includeKey`, but I see no such option when refreshing the session.